# Transfer video files to iPad Pro from PC using USB and no WiFi

Tags: usb, video, itunes, ipad, transfer

I'm looking for a solution to transfer video files from my PC that does not have WiFi to my iPad Pro 12.9 Gen 4 using USB. Then I'd like to upload those to YouTube using the iPads LTE data connection.

From what I'm seeing the only way is with iTunes? And I'm hearing that iTunes may be dropped soon?

Any suggestions?

NOTE: So I can not seem to find a way to transfer a video from my PC directly to the iPad photos/videos via USB. It wants to use iCloud. The only way I could find a way is to have an app installed on the iPad such as FTP Manager. Then in Itunes I can transfer the video to that app. Then on the iPad in that APP I can copy it to my photo library. Then from there I can open the YouTube app and upload the video.. Geeeezzzz Apple.

Comment: If and when iTunes is discontinued Apple will release software to replace it.  However, this question appears to be more of a rant about Apple, than anything and doesn’t really ask a question within scope here at Super User

Comment: thanks... yes rant, but that was after the Question, the last 2 words, really appreciate the help, I just came here to ask dumb questions

Comment: Use iTunes and accept the intentional limitations of iOS devices imposed by Apple on their devices

Comment: iTunes has never been used to transfer photo or video **from** an iDevice to a computer, only to sync from the computer. On Mac it was always iPhoto/Photos or Image Capture, all built-into the OS. On Windows it used to be Photo Viewer, now Photos.

Comment: With windows photos it appears I can only transfer from iPad to PC, in my case I want to transfer from PC to iPad

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter. Put the video files on a USB Flash drive, connect it to the Multiport Adapter along with USB-C power. On iPad open the Files APP. From there click on the flash drive and you can select a file and copy it to iPad.

Comment: any chance someone could up vote the question as this is a legitimate Q?